# scope for count children has_many relation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I have two models

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: answers
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  content     :text
#  question_id :integer
#  accept      :boolean
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null    
#  user_id     :integer
#

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :accept, :content, :question_id, :user
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :username, to: :user, allow_nil: true, prefix: 'owner'
end
```

and Question

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: questions
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  title        :string(255)
#  content      :text             default(""), not null
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
#  user_id      :integer
#  viewed_count :integer          default(0)
#

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :title, :content, :user
  attr_accessible :content, :title, :tag_list
  acts_as_taggable
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
  has_many :answers
  delegate :username, to: :user, allow_nil: true, prefix: 'owner'
  scope :owner, joins(:user)
  scope :without_answer, joins(:answers).
     select('questions.id').
     group('questions.id').
     having('count(answers.id) = 0')

  validate :validation_of_tag_list

  def self.no_answer
    Question.all.select{|question|question.answers.count == 0}
  end
```

The scope `without_answer` and class method `no_answer` theoretically should be same. However, I run them in the console as below:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
irb(main):001:0> Question.without_answer
  Question Load (0.6ms)  SELECT questions.id FROM `questions` INNER JOIN `answers` ON `answers`.`question_id` = `questions`.`id` GROUP BY questions.id HAVING count(answers.id) = 0
=> []
irb(main):002:0> Question.no_answer
  Question Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `questions`.* FROM `questions` 
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `answers` WHERE `answers`.`question_id` = 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `answers` WHERE `answers`.`question_id` = 2
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `answers` WHERE `answers`.`question_id` = 16
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `answers` WHERE `answers`.`question_id` = 17
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `answers` WHERE `answers`.`question_id` = 34
=> [#<Question id: 2, title: "Here is the second", content: "here you go\r\n", created_at: "2013-04-20 00:34:15", updated_at: "2013-04-20 00:34:15", user_id: nil, viewed_count: 0>, #<Question id: 16, title: "my question", content: "Here is my question", created_at: "2013-04-21 02:02:47", updated_at: "2013-04-23 02:29:27", user_id: 1, viewed_count: 1>, #<Question id: 17, title: "Hello", content: "me", created_at: "2013-04-23 00:37:56", updated_at: "2013-04-23 00:37:56", user_id: nil, viewed_count: 0>, #<Question id: 34, title: "Question title", content: "question content", created_at: "2013-04-23 04:57:49", updated_at: "2013-04-23 04:57:49", user_id: 42, viewed_count: 0>]
```

1. why the scope dose not work as expect?
2. which way will be better to due with such situation or even better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `without_answer` scope is very close, but needs an outer join like this:

```
scope :without_answer,
   joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN answers ON answers.question_id = questions.id').
   select('questions.id').
   group('questions.id').
   having('count(answers.id) = 0')
```

Then, you can get the count with `length`:

```
Question.without_answer.length
```

Note: if you want `without_answer` to be the same as `no_answer` (i.e. return actual Question objects), you would need to remove the `select`.

A simpler and faster way to count the unanswered questions is like this:

```
Question.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN answers ON answers.question_id = questions.id').
         where('answers.id' => nil).count
```

Also, this will return the same as `no_answer` as-is, simply use `all` instead of `count`.